# AnglularJS - ngOptions selected option with string value for the model, but objects as options

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

Been trawling for hours now trying to understand how this is meant to work.

But effectively I've got

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php $field = 'member_address_country'; ?>
    <label for="<?=$field?>">Country</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="<?=$field?>" ng-options="country.country_id as country.country_name for country in countries track by country.country_id" ng-model="a.<?=$field?>">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I've got an array of countries, stored inside `$scope.countries` as objects looking similar to

```
[
    {country_id: "1", country_name: "england"},
    {country_id: "2", country_name: "america"},
    {country_id: "3", country_name: "other"},
]
```

I've got an array of addresses which are in a ngRepeat labeled as `a` so `a.member_address_country` is a string, which will contain an int id. in this example its `"2"`

So although im using ngOptions and `track by country.country_id` and the value of the model is the id from `country_id` as expected, when the ngRepeat is rendered it just displays `-- Select --` rather than picking the object from the array, based off the tracked id.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

I've added a codepen of the issue -> http://codepen.io/owenmelbz/pen/XdxrMO?editors=1010

and another example here ->

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('testController', function($scope) {

    $scope.a = {
      member_address_country: 100
    }

    $scope.countries = [{
      country_id: 100,
      country_name: "england"
    }, {
      country_id: 200,
      country_name: "uk"
    }, {
      country_id: 300,
      country_name: "london"
    }]

  });
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group" ng-app="app" ng-controller="testController">
  <label for="member_address_country">Country</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="member_address_country" ng-options="country.country_id as country.country_name for country in countries track by country.country_id" ng-model="a.member_address_country">
  </select>model value is: {{a.member_address_country | json}}
</div>
```

Comment: You say that your array of countries is stored in a variable called `$scope.country` but in your code, you are trying to bind to a `countries` variable. Which one is the correct?

Comment: sorry that was a typo, its `$scope.countries` you can see it happening in http://codepen.io/owenmelbz/pen/XdxrMO?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<select ng-change="getName(a.member_address_country)" class="form-control" id="member_address_country" ng-options="country.country_id as country.country_name for country in countries" ng-model="a.member_address_country">
        </select> model value is: {{a.member_address_country| json}}
    Name after change = {{name}};
```

**JS**

```
    $scope.a = {
       country_id: 100,
          country_name: "england"
      }

  $scope.getName = function(countryid){
    angular.forEach($scope.countries,function(data){
      if(data.country_id == countryid){

        $scope.name = data.country_name;
      }

    });
  };
```

Comment: Hi Mohsin, `$scope.a` is not the model for the country, that contains a whole address object, so changing it to that would break everything else, the property is called `$scope.a.member_address_country` - this is what the dropdown needs to update.

Comment: k ill try with this new info

Comment: If you see this pen -> http://codepen.io/owenmelbz/pen/XdxrMO?editors=1010 you'll see that the item "england" should be selected by default, although its not, its blank

Comment: Not quite, it returns back an object, the specific issue is that it needs to return the 'string value' of country_id as mentioned in the title, which is why `track by country.country_id` is used

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are wondering why you are defaulting to the option containing your placeholder text?

```
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
```

Two things:

1. You don't need to include that option unless you have it there as a hook for something else.
2. If you do want to use that, but don't want it to be displayed by defualt (which to be honest would not make a whole lot of sense to me) then remove the selected="selected" attribute.

## Update

In that case, I took a look at your example. The person who asked you the question in the comment above is correct. Your variable has two different names: country & countries. Pick one or the other and make them match, and it should be good to go.

See:

You're referencing this variable
`country.country_id`

But in your scope, you declare

```
$scope.countries = [
{
  country_id: 100,
  country_name: "england"
},
{
  country_id: 200,
  country_name: "uk"
},
{
  country_id: 300,
  country_name: "london"
}
]
```

## Update 2

I think this is what you want or nearly:

```
ng-options="country.country_id for country in countries track by id"
```

Comment: Its just a placeholder item, will eventually be inside an `ng-if="editing_mode"` but even if you remove the placeholder item, it defaults to a blank one instead. I've just created a codepen with it -> http://codepen.io/owenmelbz/pen/XdxrMO?editors=1010 you can see the default value of the model is 100, but the select doesnt use it.

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, that was just a typo in the question, if you look at the real code example on the codepen you'll see the actual problem, unless I'm not understanding how `track by` works.

Comment: So if I replace all instances of `country.country_id` with `countries.country_id` that should fix it? As I've tried that on a fork http://codepen.io/owenmelbz/pen/pyxzOx?editors=1010 and its giving me a completely different country, and setting `undefined` in the values

Comment: I replaced the code with that, and its doing 2 things wrong now :( its setting the label of the dropdown to a value, rather than the name of the country - dont think users will know the internal IDs of our database :P and it says "model value: 100" yet picks "300". This is a pen with the suggestion -> http://codepen.io/owenmelbz/pen/mPzbZM?editors=1010